# How do you use global scripts/coding templates in mirth

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, mirth

Hi I've started using mirth, and getting the hand of what is going on.
So I have mu source and now multiple destinations with filters.
But in each destination it has the connection string details.

I have read that there are global scripts and coding templates so I can have the connection strings in once.

There seems to be a scripts tab in the channel.
Is this the global scripts and where I could have my connection string?

If you could give me an example/screen shots then that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select *Channels* in the top navigation pan on the left side, then under *Channel Tasks* click *Edit Global Scripts*. These are scripts that apply to all channels at different stages. One of the examples, is to use Deploy Global Script to define GlobalMap variables such as source and destination folders, or to verify database connection before any channel tries to access it, etc.

Comment: Ah thanks, I've been playing with this, but I can get a handle on it. 
I'm basically just wanting to set a function or a variable that I can use within my destination (database writer, I'm using the Javascript) to connect to my databases preferably every time a message needs to be dealt with. Just trying to get the connection details in one place. What is the best way for this?

Comment: Right I've got it all working, man there are are alot of settings, sock one up and your done for!
The way I choose for this is go to the channel->scripts tab(at the top);
deploy enter in the string
dbConn = DatabaseConnectionFactory.createDatabaseConnection('net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver','jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://xxx:xxx/xxxxx','user','pass');
attatch to global map
globalMap.put('gdbConn', dbConn );

In the database write you can now write
dbConn =  globalMap.get('gdbConn');

but don't close it!